# Where condition right after Or condition not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I use only one `OR` condition from the 3 `OR` conditions, the `where` clause is not working.

```
 $this->db->where('(delivery_date BETWEEN "'.$from.'" AND "'.$to.'") ');
    $this->db->or_where('order_date BETWEEN "'.$odfrom.'" AND "'.$odto.'"');
     $this->db->or_where('mumbai_date BETWEEN "'.$mdfrom.'" AND "'.$mdto.'"');
    $this->db->where('order_location',$sess_location);
    $this->db->where('designer_id',$sess_designer_id);
    $this->db->where('is_deleted=',0);
    $query= $this->db->limit($length,$start)->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: Looks like you missed round brackets at line 2 and 3.

Comment: Show a result SQL query you want or look at current  one by `echo $this->db->last_query();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In codeigniter round "or_where" conditions with brackets;

```
$this->db->where('(delivery_date BETWEEN "'.$from.'" AND "'.$to.'") ');
$this->db->where('((order_date BETWEEN "'.$odfrom.'" AND "'.$odto
                 .'") OR (mumbai_date BETWEEN "'.$mdfrom.'" AND "'.$mdto.'"))',NULL,false);

$this->db->where('order_location',$sess_location);
$this->db->where('designer_id',$sess_designer_id);
$this->db->where('is_deleted=',0);
$query= $this->db->limit($length,$start)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

although this question already has an answer i might add -

> you never ever should use **unescaped data** in your queries because you are fully open to SQL Injections - please read the [QueryBuilder documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping) and the [Queries Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html?highlight=escape#escaping-queries) carefully - especially the part with escaping.

so to speak the following code is more suitable for your case

```
$query = $this->db
    ->group_start()
        ->where('delivery_date >=', $from)
        ->where('delivery_date <=', $to)
    ->group_end()   
    ->group_start()
        ->group_start()
            ->where('order_date >=', $odfrom)
            ->where('order_date <=', $odto)
        ->group_end()
        ->or_group_start()
            ->where('mumbai_date >=', $mdfrom)
            ->where('mumbai_date <=', $mdto)
        ->group_end()
    ->group_end()
    ->where('order_location', $sess_location)
    ->where('designer_id',$sess_designer_id)
    ->where('is_deleted=',0)
    ->limit($length, $start)
    ->get();
```

Or if you really want to use `between` you can do that like

```
$query = $this->db
    ->group_start()
        ->where('delivery_date BETWEEN '.$this->db->escape($from).' AND '.$this->db->escape($to))
    ->group_end()   
    ->group_start()
        ->group_start()
            ->where('order_date BETWEEN '.$this->db->escape($odfrom).' AND '.$this->db->escape($odto))
        ->group_end()
        ->or_group_start()
            ->where('mumbai_date BETWEEN '.$this->db->escape($mdfrom).' AND '.$this->db->escape($mdto))
        ->group_end()
    ->group_end()
    ->where('order_location', $sess_location)
    ->where('designer_id',$sess_designer_id)
    ->where('is_deleted=',0)
    ->limit($length, $start)
    ->get();
```